# JQuery Validation not working for UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to add JQuery validation for a form which has JQUery UI tabs in. The form validates fine for the first tab that is open but not for the hidden ones. Is there a way to validate all tabs?

I have tried using:

```
ignore:""
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything.

**Here's a copy of my code:**

http://pastebin.com/ucT9vBgq

Does anyone know how I can validate all tabs in the form?

Edit:

Here's just the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
        var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
            ignore:"",
            groups: {
                        birthdate: "birthdateDay birthdateMonth birthdateYear"
                },
                //errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
                //      if (/^birthdate/.test(element[0].name)) {
                //              label.insertAfter("#birthdateYear");
                //      } else {
                //              label.insertAfter(element);
                //      }
                //}
        });

        $.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: ""
        });
```

Comment: can you paste the respective jQuery code here?

Comment: The proper way to disable the ignoring of hidden fields is `ignore: []`

Comment: You're going to have to do more explaining within the OP instead of just dumping the code in a pastebin.  I noticed that you're including `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` here.  If that's true, then you cannot call `.validate()` because that's already handled by your framework.  Perhaps editing your OP to mention which framework and unobtrusive validation would be best.